# How to run SQL PLUS in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, oracle, sql

I have installed SQL PLUS from instructions I got from here[SQL PLUS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Oracle%20Instant%20Client) .. BUt now I don't know how to start whenever I start it using sqlplus64 command it asks for username and password which I don't get during it's installation.
Now I want to know how to start SQL PLUS

Answer (score 1):

Your default users are sys and system.  According to the Oracle website the passwords are displayed in a message during installation, but I guess you didn't see it?

It used to be that the default users had default passwords. For sys it was: change_on_install and for system: manager.  As you can guess these weren't changed on install, which generally caused a major security risk so maybe this is why Oracle stopped using them.

So my advice would be:
- try the above default passwords and hope they work (which is unlikely);
- reinstall the database and look for the message giving you passwords.

Once you are logged in as sys, create a day-to-day user and use it for your project.  Don't use sys or system - they are too powerful and to be used for administration only.

Comment: I guess they have changed the password because they don't work. what to do?